# Get boolean from SoapObject (kSOAP2)

Tags: android, boolean, ksoap2

I'm trying to get a boolean value from a SoapObject, I've gotten from a response from a web server using kSOAP2 in Android...

I've saved the response form the web call in a SoapObject:

```
SoapObject sResult = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
```

and I'm iterating through the response and grabbing the values

```
SoapObject soapresults = (SoapObject)sResult.getProperty(0);

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    SoapObject mail = (SoapObject)soapresults.getProperty(i);

    /*Getting the values here*/   
}
```

A mail SoapObject will be similar to this:

> MessageInstance=anyType{AuthorName=Børnehaven;
>   CreatedAtUtc=2012-04-10T18:30:00; Id=631; MessageBody=Husk i morgen;
>   Recipient=anyType{FullName=null; Id=2104535421; IsRead=true;
>   ReadAtUtc=2012-04-10T18:30:00; }; };

And the only value I'm having trouble grabbing is the "IsRead" value, which I want to store as a boolean...

I've tried a few things:

```
(Boolean)mail.getProperty("IsRead");
((Boolean) mail.getProperty("IsRead")).booleanValue();
```

But I keep getting:

> W/System.err(1283): java.lang.RuntimeException: illegal property:
>   IsRead

What is the correct way of getting it?

Comment: Try to get the Property `Recipient` & then loop it again to get `IsRead` property like you have done for `MessageInstance`. I think you will get it easily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this code snippet:

```
SoapObject soRecipient = (SoapObject) mail.getProperty("Recipient");

boolean isRead = Boolean.parseBoolean(soRecipient.getPropertyAsString("IsRead"));
String fullName = soRecipient.getPropertyAsString("FullName");
String id = soRecipient.getPropertyAsString("Id");
String readAtUtc = soRecipient.getPropertyAsString("ReadAtUtc");
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error... It's weird, I've tried all the ways of converting a string to boolean that I've could find... I've also tried simply getting it to a string first, and then converting that string, but I still get the same error...

Comment: First this:
SoapObject soRecipient = (SoapObject) mail.getProperty("Recipient");

Comment: After this:
boolean isRead = Boolean.parseBoolean(soRecipient.getPropertyAsString("IsRead"));

Comment: Oh, damn.. I'm an idiot :) I knew this, just forget that is was deeper nested than the others... Thanks for correcting my brain-fart :)

Comment: Hi Guys, In my case the response that i get from Webservice is dynamic(i.e), For instance, it may contain a certain property or may not. In that scenario, How can i handle this illegal Property exception.

Comment: SoapObject has `hasProperty(propertyName)` method that returns a boolean value. You can use this with `if-else`

Comment: @OguzOzkeroglu: Can you please help me for Soap Object issue i am want to fetch values from one soap Object which is nested. Or can you tell me how to access the value part soapObject?

Comment: @user1368800: need help for SoapObject Parsing can you please tell me how get value part from SoapObject?

Comment: @OguzOzkeroglu: yes i am getting values in SoapObject in Value part of object but i am unable to retrive from it. like in value part there is elementData in their value part again i get some values and so on its nested....