# Get string from KSoap Response

Tags: android, xml, soap, ksoap

My question is somewhat similar to [Get boolean from SoapObject (kSOAP2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544243/get-boolean-from-soapobject-ksoap2),

so, the thing is my soap response is something like

```
anyType{ResCode=100; TransID=123456; Signature=abc123def456; OutputParams=anyType{params=anyType{useruid=a-e23; status=1; fullname=john smith; }; }; }
```

pretty much with the same format as the link above, but using the answers provided there I still keep getting

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: illegal property: useruid
```

and the code that i used was

```
//resp = resp.getProperty("OutputParams");
//resp = (SoapObject) resp.getProperty("params");
//str = resp.getPropertyAsString("useruid");
str = resp.getPropertyAsString("params");
```

all these didn't work... anybody has more ideas?

Comment: have you noticed, that you try to get "userid" instead of "useruid"?

Comment: sorry, that was a typo i edited the answer to reflect the update..

Comment: How you initialized the 'resp'? please put logical code fragment that should work on same SOAP Message given above. Also, please post the complete SOAP Message.

Comment: have you got the whole response in a string?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help guys, I figured out the problem its cause of my carelessness when I didn't try the combinations as below

```
resp = (SoapObject) resp.getProperty("OutputParams");
resp = (SoapObject) resp.getProperty("params");
str = resp.getPropertyAsString("useruid");
```